# Why do people look at me sometimes and make remarks that I should sleep, or that I look ill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just created my new character 2 hours ago and I've reached a town. Sometimes random guards will comment that I look ill, or that I should rest. "You look sick, honey. Do you want to lie down?", isn't uncommon.

Did I unexpectedly get vampirism? I didn't fight any vampires, only a couple of wolves and bandits.

I'm a dark elf, so maybe my race isn't seen much around Skyrim and the remarks are more roleplay than actual illness.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you got a disease, but that's just me guessing - the NPC in the TES series had a habit of commenting on your condition in such a way at least from Morrowind on, if not earlier.

Comment: I'm a breton and I keep hearing that too. I'm not diseased tho.

Comment: I dont think it has to do with race, Im an Imperial and get the same remarks. maybe a bug?

Comment: Probably just a critic to your real life.
NPCS inside a game,are telling you to get some sleep,because you probably look sick after all that time playing Skyrim. Just kidding, @RavenDreamer answered it right, im with Rockjoint since i started playing Skyrim. Damn disease, i remember the Worm or w.e that bit me,and im still sick.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You might want to double-check your wolf bites. Wolves have a chance of carrying "Rockjoint", a disease which decreases your melee damage dealt. NPCs use those responses for *all* diseases, not just <strike>Porphyric Hemophilia</strike> **Sanguinare Vampiris** (aka, Vampirism).

So the good news: You're probably not accidentally a vampire.

But the NPCs are probably right too - you're suffering from *something*. The simplest way to fix all this is to cast a Cure Disease spell on yourself, chug a Cure Disease Potion, or the like.

Visiting a temple in any city and praying at their altar will instantly cleanse non-vampire / werewolf diseases from the afflicted, *and* give you a temporary buff to boot.

Comment: I did have Rockjoint! A good prayer at the alter and I'm good. :D

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this is.  I've had alchemists say I look like I might have Ataxia - but I'm a werewolf, immune to disease!

Comment: @Iszi - Arcadia (The alchemist in Whiterun) thinks *everyone* has Ataxia. She's a hypochondriac, and projects onto others.

Comment: Is there actually a cure disease spell in Skyrim?

Comment: @TZHX: Yes and no.  *Yes*, because technically speaking, the altar blessings are implemented as spells that the altar casts on you.  *No*, because there is no spell you can cast yourself without mods.

Answer (score 26):

Another easy way to check is to go to your "active effects" on magica. If any effects are marked in red, these are negative/hurtful, and the description will tell you if it's a disease.

Answer (score 3):

I made the palest Wood Elf possible and I get told I look sick all the time, but I have no active effects and even after praying I still get told I look sick.

I've never seen a Nord with a tan anyway so I don't know why a pale Elf is something that needs to be commented on.

Comment: Yeah, Dolphine there are no tanned nords. Is she a nord though? Anyway, this keeps happening to me too all the time, irrelevantly of whether I am sick or not and the apothecaries tell me that they think there's something wrong with me when there's nothing so I guess that it has to do with your race (dunmer for me).

Comment: I'm a High Elf, and always presumed this to be the case also.