# How can I tell what diseases I have?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Related: [Why do people look at me sometimes and make remarks that I should sleep, or that I look ill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34472/why-do-people-look-at-me-sometimes-and-make-remarks-that-i-should-sleep-or-that)

So I contract a disease, and people are telling me I look sick, but I don't know what disease I have or how it affects me. I don't see it anywhere under 'General Stats'.

How can I tell what disease I've contracted?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Basically, what you can do is go under the main menu, select the magic tab and click **Active Effects**. If you currently have a disease, the effects will show up here in red (connoting a negative effect). Here are the diseases that you can contract in Skyrim as per the [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Diseases_%28Skyrim%29):

- **Ataxia:** Lockpicking & Pickpocket become 25% harder. This disease is contracted from traps and Skeevers.
- **Black Heart Blight** (Dragonborn DLC only)**:** Drains 10 points from carry weight.
- **Bone Break Fever:** -25 Stamina. Contracted from Traps, Bears.
- **Brain Rot:** -25 Magicka. Contracted from Traps, Hagraven
- **Droops** (Dragonborn DLC only)**:** One-handed and two-handed weapon damage is 15% lower. Contracted from Ash Hoppers.
- **Rattles:** Stamina recovers 50% slower. Contracted from Traps and Chaurus
- **Rockjoint:** 25% less effective with melee weapons. Contracted from Traps, Wolves and Foxes
- **Sanguinare Vampiris:** -25% health, progresses to Vampirism. Contracted from Vampires
- **Witbane:** Magicka recovers 50% slower. Contracted from Traps and Sabrecat.
- **Lycanthropy:** Transformation into a Werewolf.

Comment: It does tell you the name of the disease in big red letters in the middle of the screen, well it does for me...

Comment: Wow yeah....shows how much I'm paying attention. Lol. I'll edit my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Protip: Quick Magic screen access is `p` for us PC players.

Comment: Dragonslayer's Blessing isn't a disease. It's an effect from a ritual performed in the quest you mentioned. As a werewolf, I am immune to disease, but I received the blessing successfully.

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop Thanks for pointing that out! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you got it from. The best way to tell which disease you have is to (if your on the 360 like i am) press B switch over to Magic, and go to Active Effects. It will tell you which kind of disease you have.